# Eclipse Android App - The Application has stopped unexpectedly. Please try again

Tags: android, eclipse

I have problem with my application for android (TelephonyManager Service). When I run app with code without getters it works, but if I use get() function app send me a message "The Application has stopped unexpectedly. Please try again". I really don't know what's wrong.

My "bad" code:

```
package com.example.tc;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.telephony.TelephonyManager;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.os.Build;

public class TC1 extends ActionBarActivity {

TextView textView1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {


    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_tc1);

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
    }

    textView1=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);  

    //Get the instance of TelephonyManager  
    TelephonyManager  tm=(TelephonyManager)getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);  




    //Calling the methods of TelephonyManager the returns the information 
    //If I remove this code app works 
    String IMEINumber=tm.getDeviceId();  



}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.tc1, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

/**
 * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
 */
public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

    public PlaceholderFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_tc1, container,
                false);
        return rootView;
    }
}
```

}

Layout.activity_tc1.xml:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/container"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.tc.TC1"
tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame" />
```

Layout.fragment_tc1.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.tc.TC1$PlaceholderFragment" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Phone Details:" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="68dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:text="aaaa" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

</RelativeLayout>
```

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.tc"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.tc.TC1"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: error log <------------->

Answer (score 1):

The [official documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html#getDeviceId%28%29) for `getDeviceID` says

```
Returns the unique device ID, for example, the IMEI for GSM and the MEID or ESN for CDMA phones. Return null if device ID is not available. 

**Requires Permission: READ_PHONE_STATE**
```

You have not given that `READ_PHONE_STATE` permission in your manifest file.

Answer (score 0):

ADD PERMISSION IN MANIFEST FILE

```
TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
// get IMEI
String imei = tm.getDeviceId();
//get The Phone Number
String phone = tm.getLine1Number();
```

Manifest

```
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
```